# Bindable properties of Xamarin forms project are not working in MAUI

Tags: xamarin, maui

During the migration of `Xamarin forms` application to `.Net MAUI`, Forms project's custom controls  `BindableProperty` showing errors when I use `BindableProperties` in MAUI project

```
The non-generic method 'BindableProperty.Create(string, Type, Type, object, BindingMode, BindableProperty.ValidateValueDelegate, BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangedDelegate, BindableProperty.BindingPropertyChangingDelegate, BindableProperty.CoerceValueDelegate, BindableProperty.CreateDefaultValueDelegate)' cannot be used with type arguments (net7.0-maccatalyst)
```

This is my code

```
namespace PRojall
{
    public partial class CustomImage : Grid
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty StatusProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomImage, ImageStatus>(p => p.Status, ImageStatus.Loading, propertyChanged: OnStatusChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty SourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomImage, ImageSource>(p => p.Source, null, propertyChanged: OnSourceChanged);

        public static readonly BindableProperty AspectProperty = BindableProperty.Create<CustomImage, Aspect>(p => p.Aspect, Aspect.AspectFit,propertyChanged: OnAspectChanged);


        public CustomImage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetImage(ImageStatus.Loading);
        }

        public ImageStatus Status
        {
            get { return (ImageStatus)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); SetImage(value); }
        }

        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public Aspect Aspect 
        { 
            get { return (Aspect)GetValue(AspectProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AspectProperty, value); }
        }


        private static void OnStatusChanged(BindableObject bindable, ImageStatus oldValue, ImageStatus newValue)
        {
            var obj = bindable as CustomImage;
            if (obj != null && oldValue != newValue)
            {
                obj.SetImage(newValue);
            }

        }

        private static void OnAspectChanged(BindableObject bindable, Aspect oldValue, Aspect newValue)
        {
            var obj = bindable as CustomImage;
            if (obj != null && oldValue != newValue)
            {
                obj.image.Aspect = newValue;
            }

        }


        private static void OnSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, ImageSource oldValue, ImageSource newValue)
        {
            var obj = bindable as CustomImage;
            if (obj != null && oldValue != newValue && newValue != null)
            {
                obj.image.Source = newValue;
            }
        }
        private void SetImage(ImageStatus status)
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case ImageStatus.Loading:
                    this.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("loading.png");
                    break;
                case ImageStatus.Error:
                    this.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("error.png");
                    break;

                case ImageStatus.NoImage:
                    this.Source = ImageSource.FromFile("noimage.png");
                    break;
            };
        }

    }
}
```

These are the errors coming in BindableProperties

[image]

How can I use this code in MAUI project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Xamarin.Forms code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableProperty.cs#L132) for this, these `Create` overloads have been obsoleted for a long time. That is probably also why they were finally removed for .NET MAUI.

You want to get rid of the types that you define between the angle brackets, so turn `BindableProperty.Create<CustomImage, ImageStatus>()` into `BindableProperty.Create()`.

Then from there, there are a couple of mandatory parameters. In case of the above example, the full declaration should probably look like:

`BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Source), typeof(ImageStatus), typeof(CustomImage), ImageStatus.Loading, propertyChanged: OnStatusChanged);`

So basically the types that you define in angle brackets move to the parameters as the third and second parameter respectively.

Comment: This works for me for the current example. How do I determine first param for other controls. Like one I have `CustomPicker : Picker` ?

Comment: IntelliSense/documentation should help you with that. This is the source in .NET MAUI: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/BindableProperty.cs#L143 the first parameter is the property name. So the regular property that is associated with this BindableProperty. Basically what you had as p => p.Status, p.Source and p.Aspect. You can go with magic strings `"Status"` but best to go with `nameof(Status)`

Comment: Also, make sure all your BIndableProperties follow the naming convention you use here: the property name (Status) followed by `Property`. (Looks like you are doing this already.) As mentioned in [Bindable Property / Create a Property (Important note)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties#create-a-property).